# Getting occassional "Can't find variable: google" error using Google Maps in Angular 2 web app

Tags: google-maps, angular, google-maps-api-3, typescript, webpack

I'm building a store locator using the Google Maps API, but occasionally running into the error:

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: google
```

This isn't a Typings error as I've added Google Maps typings as well as tried declaring

```
declare var google: any
```

at the top.

Strangely, if I navigate to the route where this service is being utilized from the homepage, I'm not getting the error. It's only when I try to load the route directly or refresh on this route. I have a feeling it's because I'm loading the Google Maps API from my index.html file and it's grabbing the file after the app is initiating. Is there a way to ensure that it happens before with Webpack or something?

This is the body of my index.html:

```
<app></app>

<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[mykeyhere]" async defer></script>
<script src="assets/scripts/web-animations/web-animations.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/scripts/instafeed/instafeed.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/animation.gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
```